# Android Studio's memory monitor shows activity still in memory even after finish()

Tags: android, android-studio

Looking at a java heap dump from the memory monitor (window 6: Android Monitor/Monitors in AS), I notice my LoginActivity and LoginFragment are still in memory even though I called activity.finish() on my LoginActivity when launching my post-login activity. The LoginActivity is not on the back stack (the back button just closes the app from my post-login activity), so why didn't activity.finish() clear it from memory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Memory is cleaned up by a garbage collector, which runs occasionally and looks for objects no longer in use to remove from memory. It may be at the time of the dump, the garbage collector hasn't run yet. You can force it to run by hitting the "Garbage Truck" icon in the memory section of the monitor.

It may also be that a reference to your Activity is being held onto, so the garbage collector isn't freeing it up. Check for anywhere you are passing in "this" (the Activity) to a method as a context parameter. Trying passing Activity.getApplicationContext() instead, that way it is the applications context (that won't get recycled anyway) being passed around.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! It's not the garbage collection so must be a reference somewhere. When I run "Analyzer Tasks" it says it's a leaky activity. Are there any tools that could help me track down where it is being held?

Comment: I have tracked it down and passed activity.getApplicationContext() instead which fixed it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There are potentially two reasons:

1. The Activity is still reachable from some other object
2. The garbage collector did not run since it became unreachable

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I started my post-login activity using "StartActivityForResult()" then did LoginActivity.finish() (because I'm using a launcher class that does that by default). Does doing the former rather than "StartActivity()" secretly keep a reference to the launching activity?